# Trying to iterate through a list with strings to generate two separate lists

Tags: python

so the question I'm running into an issue with is below. I'm in Comp Sci 1 so we've learned only the rudiments so far, like split(), count(), append, lists, etc.

> In XYZ University, upper level math classes are numbered 300 and up. Upper level English classes are numbered 200 and up. Upper level Psychology classes are 400 and up. Create two lists, upper and lower. Assign each course in classes to the correct list, upper or lower. HINT: remember, you can convert some strings to different types!

The code I've written is below and I was expecting the lists to populate each value on the list (e.g. "MATH 150") on two separate lists.

```
classes = ["MATH 150", "PSYCH 111", "PSYCH 313", "PSYCH 412", "MATH 300", "MATH 404", "MATH 206", "ENG 100", "ENG 103", "ENG 201", "PSYCH 508", "ENG 220", "ENG 125", "ENG 124"]
# math classes >= 300 == upper
# english classes >= 200 == upper
# pscyh classes >= 400 == upper
upper = []
lower = []

for c in classes:
    course_cat = c.split()[0]
    course_number = int(c.split()[1])
    #print(course_cat)
    #print(course_number)
    if course_cat in c == "MATH":
        if course_number in c >= 300:
                upper.append(c)
        else:
                lower.append(c)
    elif course_cat in c == "ENG":
        if course_number in c >= 200:
                upper.append(c)
        else:
            lower.append(c)
    elif course_cat in c == "PSYCH":
        if course_number in c >= 400:
            upper.append(c)
        else:
            lower.append(c)
                
print(upper)
print(lower)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if course_cat in c == "MATH":`? That should just be `if course_cat == "MATH":`

Comment: You do the same thing with `if course_number in c >= 300:`. Why do you keep writing `in c`?

Comment: Please make sure you include all parts of a [mre]

Comment: @Julien What's missing?

Comment: Actual result vs expected, not just `print(...)` and wordy description of expectation. Ideally we shouldn't need to copy paste and run to see.

Comment: AS far as I can see your issue is the incorrect syntax mentioned by @Barmer. Just change your conditional statements to `if course_cat == "MATH":` etc.

Comment: When you write multiple comparison operators in a single expression, it's equivalent  to `if course_cat in c and c == "MATH":` These conditions will never be true.

Comment: @Julien, thanks for the heads up on this convention. I'll do my best to adhere to this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace`course_cat in c == "MATH"` for `course_cat == "MATH"` and `course_number in c >= 300` for course_number >= 300. Same for ENG, PSYCH

Answer (score 1):

This is a common pitfall. When you write

```
if course_cat in c == "MATH"
```

What you are really writing is:

```
if (course_cat in c) and (c == "MATH")
# if ("MATH" in "MATH 150") and ("MATH 150" == "MATH")
```

What you would want is simply `if course_cat == "MATH"`

---

To get more advanced in this example, you could make a helper function to determine the results, and could use a lookup dictionary for the thresholds.

```
upper_levels = {"MATH": 300, "ENG": 200, "PSYCH": 400}

def is_upper_level(class_name_level):
    name, level = class_name.split()
    return int(level) >= upper_levels[name]


for c in classes:
    if is_upper_level(c):
        upper.append(c)
    else:
        lower.append(c)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
classes = ["MATH 150", "PSYCH 111", "PSYCH 313", "PSYCH 412", "MATH 300", "MATH 404", "MATH 206", "ENG 100", "ENG 103", "ENG 201", "PSYCH 508", "ENG 220", "ENG 125", "ENG 124"]
upper = []
lower = []

for c in classes:
    course_cat, course_number = c.split()  # This unpacks the split list directly into two variables
    course_number = int(course_number)  # Convert the course number to an integer

    if course_cat == "MATH":
        if course_number >= 300:
            upper.append(c)
        else:
            lower.append(c)
    elif course_cat == "ENG":
        if course_number >= 200:
            upper.append(c)
        else:
            lower.append(c)
    elif course_cat == "PSYCH":
        if course_number >= 400:
            upper.append(c)
        else:
            lower.append(c)

print("Upper Level Classes:", upper)
print("Lower Level Classes:", lower)
```